# Unable to get auth email as field value in view (larave5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working on laravel 5.3 and i want to get authenticated user email as my field value my field code is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ isset($student->email) ? $student->email : '{{Auth::user()->email}}' }}" required />
 </div>
```

Here above i tried as **{{Auth::user()->id}}' }}** but its give syntax error if

> syntax error, unexpected '}'

If i try with single bracket it prints as it is

Comment: don't use '{{Auth::user()->email}}' }}' use only value 'Auth::user()->email, you have already used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ isset($student->email) ? $student->email : Auth::user()->email }}" required />
```

Copy paste this code,
you tried to give {{}} inside {{}} to fetch auth details.

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: I think @recoverymen you have to accept this as correct answer

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, you can accept my answer and upvote it thanks !

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ isset($student->email) ? $student->email : Auth::user()->email }}" required />`

Try,

```
@php($email=Auth::user()->email)
@if(isset($student->email))
$email=$student->email
@endif
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email }}" required />
```